# Leaflet multiOptionsPolyline - draws color on the next segment instead of the right one

Tags: leaflet, javascript, line

It's my first time using `multiOptionsPolyline` to draw a multicolor polyline from an array of LatLng points, with red segments if distance is smaller or equal to 90m and green if bigger.

```
var polyLine = L.multiOptionsPolyline(latlngs, {
        multiOptions: {
            optionIdxFn: function (latLng, prevLatLng, index) {
                //if (index == 0) return 0;
                if (map.distance(latLng, prevLatLng) <= 90)
                    return 0;
                return 1;
            },
            options: [{
                color: 'red',
                className: 'polyline-fill'
            },
            {
                color: 'green',
                className: 'polyline-nofill',
                interactive: false
            }
            ]
        },
        weight: 3
    }).addTo(map);
```

If I have an array of elements `var latlngs = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J]` and only `D->E` (D-`prevLatLng` and E-`latLng` in `optionIdxFn` function) is bigger than 90m, the segment between D and E should be green and the other red.

My only issue is that the green color is attached to the next segment (E->F), instead of the correct one and I cannot understand what am I doing wrong. The same thing happens even if I have, let's say D->E and E->F greater than 90m. E->F becomes green and F->G. The green color applies with an offset of one segment.

Comment: Use `latlngs[index-1]` and `latlngs[index-2]` instead of `latLng` and `prevLatLng`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Can you please give me an example? I've tried changing to latlngs[index-1] and latlngs[index-2] instead of latLng and prevLatLng inside optionIdxFn but still doesn't apply the color right

Comment: Turns out the off-by-one error is in the opposite direction: use `latlngs[index]` and `latlngs[index+1]` (which should be easy to notice, since using `i` and `i-1` shifted the colouring even further). I suggest you polish up https://plnkr.co/edit/7qx3YZ2JirwGhZyX , answer yourself, and submit a bug report & fix to the multioptionspolyline repo.